# JS: Boxy, how to tween newly created dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, boxy

I'm using http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/ to create popups. e.g. my code looks like this:

JS

```
 $('.boxy').boxy();


<a id="popuplink" class="boxy" href="#popup" title="Sample popup">Popup</a>

<div id="popup" style="display:none">
     Some big content
</div>
```

The problem is that my content is a bit big, so I am not happy about how boxy centers it. I want to display it higher on the page. So I want to tween the dialog box after it's created. How do I do that. (I see correspondent function in documentation, but don't understand how and from which place to call it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added event listener to the link and created new boxy container after getting the event. Sorry for asking stupid questions